# make website offline available and browse later without 3G connection

Tags: 3g, offline

I have a Nexus 7 (wireless only) and no smart phone. How to make a web site offline (mirror) available that I later can read it without internet connection?

> example site http://www.tagesanzeiger.ch

I don't wish articles, I wish full web site with all articles. Tried several apps from Play Store, but they crashes when feeding with my URL.

Comment: Just one page or the entire site with all sub-pages?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik He said "Website" which is a collection of webpages...

Comment: I don't think this is possible, even in theory: if the site that you want to mirror does anything dynamic -- that is, if the pages it displays are computed rather than simply static, how would your phone do that computation?

An example of the sort of dynamic computation I'm talking about: google.  Even if you somehow "mirrored" google onto your tablet, if you then went to the (mirrored) google home page, and entered a search term, how on Earth could your tablet possibly give you the correct result?

I suspect that most web sites are enough like Google that mirroring them would be pointless.

Comment: You seriously want the full web site? Looking at it, it could be huge (in the several gigabyte range). @offby1 Well the site he linked to seems to do all rendering on the server side, so it should be as *"easy"* as downloading every page and the images, stylesheets than rewriting all urls. On the desktop there are software that do this. In fact it could be as simple as a few dozen LOC.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any app for Android that can mirror an entire website. However there are plenty available for computers. I don't have experience with any of them, so I can'T give you recommendations. A Google search revealed a few candidates that could do the job. [[1]](http://sourceforge.net/projects/websitecopier/) [[2]](http://download.cnet.com/HTTrack-Website-Copier/3000-2377_4-10039773.html) [[3]](http://www.inspyder.com/products/Web2Disk/Website-Copier.aspx)
These should download the individual pages and the necessary resources like stylesheets, images and javascript files.

After you've downloaded the site copy it to your SD card and use [web server app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xeustechnologies.android.kws) to serve it locally. Just open up your browser and point it to the web server's address.